# rows as dictionary into columns of dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with two columns, the second column has values as dictionary. I'm trying to convert the key of the dictionary into separate columns of the dataframe.

```
df
    name  values
    a     {'king':'diamond','queen':'spade','jack':'club'}
    a     {'king':'spade','queen':'club','jack':'diamond'} 
    b     {'king':'club','queen':'diamond','jack':'spade'}
    b     {'king':'spade','queen':'spade','jack':'diamond'}
```

Expected Output

```
df
    name  king    queen   jack 
    a     diamond spade   club
    a     spade   club    diamond
    b     club    diamond spade
    b     spade   spade   diamond
```

I was thinking of using `pandas.DataFrame()` but not sure how it would be applied to a column in a dataframe. What should be the approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the values actual dicts, or strings that look like dictionaries?

Comment: Actual dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do,

```
print(df.set_index("name")['value'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index())

  name     king    queen     jack
0    a  diamond    spade     club
1    a    spade     club  diamond
2    b     club  diamond    spade
3    b    spade    spade  diamond
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df["values"]))], axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
  name                                             values     king    queen  \
0    a  {'king': 'diamond', 'queen': 'spade', 'jack': ...  diamond    spade   
1    a  {'king': 'spade', 'queen': 'club', 'jack': 'di...    spade     club   
2    b  {'king': 'club', 'queen': 'diamond', 'jack': '...     club  diamond   
3    b  {'king': 'spade', 'queen': 'spade', 'jack': 'd...    spade    spade   

      jack  
0     club  
1  diamond  
2    spade  
3  diamond
```